# NEO analysis tutorial and data

Tags: wgcna

I was reading Jason Aten's paper [Using genetic markers to orient the edges in quantitative trait networks: The NEO software](https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1752-0509-2-34), which states

> The NEO software can be used to orient the edges of gene co-expression networks or quantitative trait networks if the edges can be anchored to genetic marker data. R software tutorials, data, and supplementary material can be downloaded from: http://www.genetics.ucla.edu/labs/horvath/aten/NEO

But it seems the site is down, does anyone know where can I access these data?

Comment: Try emailing the author. The horvath UCLA URL is one of the most notorious dead websites.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comment above, I would suggest emailing the corresponding author. Scientific articles usually list the email of the corresponding author and this would be the most logical first step in addressing the missing materials.